# ./configure error xft.pc is missing

Tags: compiling

i try to install something and did as asked in the readme ./configure but it gives me the following error:

```
checking for xft... Package xft was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xft.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'xft' found
configure: error: Library requirements (xft) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix
```

I'm not really familiar with linux so i googled a bit and came across the command "locate xft.pc"
But it doesnt give me any output so i assume i'm missing the xft.pc. 
I tried "sudo apt-get xft.pc" but that didnt helped either. 
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The package you need to install is named **libxft-dev**: `sudo apt-get -y install libxft-dev`